# NodeJs:Redirect to another page and pass values

Tags: node.js

How to redirect with passing values to that HTML?

here is my code:

```
app.get("/test",function(req,res){

res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views/test.html'));
});
```

Comment: That particular page was redirected successful, but I don't know how to pass values to a test.html page.

Comment: I don't know how to pass value to a html file. But you can add `?` or `#` followed by value when redirect to a url, or pass value to a page written in js template like ejs

Comment: thanks, can you please give some example with code.

Comment: [express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) gives a complete example